# How do I have my webpage showing all hyperlink for all entries in a column

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this JSP/Servlet based application where I have the database columns output shown in a table. But, I want one of the column contents to come out as hyperlinks for all 100 entries.

How should I be able to do that? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Can you improve this question by posting a snippet of the code that generates your table?  In general though - you want to change <td><%= value %></td>  into <td><a href="<%=value%>"><%=value %></a></td>.  Value will have to be a valid URL though.

Comment: Please ask the question in brief ....

Comment: The SQL query is following:

Comment: public static final String GET_APPLICATION_ADMIN_SERVER_SQL = "SELECT *" + " FROM " + AppProperties.Table.APPLICATIONSILOADMINSERVER 
   + " ORDER BY ID ASC";

Comment: Why do have two <%=value %> s up there?

Comment: The way I have the rows:       <td><select class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"
       name="SELECT_APP" id="SELECT_APP" onchange="getServerHealth()"><%=request.getAttribute("APP_LIST")%></select>

      </td>

Comment: How do I change that <TD>...</TD> string?            Sorry for many comments, but, the way add comments section is setup, as soon as I press enter, the comments get added.

Comment: Can someone please help me on how can I have HTML popup contents coming from the database?